# How to get OAuth2.0 Token for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: python, firebase, oauth-2.0, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have set up my web app to receive Firebase Cloud Messages, but in order to send them I understand that I need an OAuth2.0 Token, which is generated from my Service Account private key. I have downloaded the key and installed Google API Client Library for Python. This is my code:

```
from oauth2client import *
def _get_access_token():
  """Retrieve a valid access token that can be used to authorize requests.

  :return: Access token.
  """
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      'service-account.json', FCM_SCOPE)
  access_token_info = credentials.get_access_token()
  return access_token_info.access_token

_get_access_token()
```

When I run that, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-oauth-token.py", line 11, in <module>
    _get_access_token()
  File "get-oauth-token.py", line 7, in _get_access_token
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
NameError: name 'ServiceAccountCredentials' is not defined
```

I assume that I'm missing an import, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: `from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials`  But the `FCM_SCOPE` I don't know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should solve:

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
fsm_scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'

def _get_access_token():
    """Retrieve a valid access token that can be used to authorize requests.

    :return: Access token.
    """
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        'service-account.json', fsm_scope)
    access_token_info = credentials.get_access_token()
    return access_token_info.access_token

_get_access_token()
```

Comment: @jiamo Do you know how to do this in .Net or JavaScript?

Comment: is there an analogue perl solution?